# Obtaining British citizenship through naturalization as EEA citizen

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, citizenship, naturalization

I am Lithuanian (EEA European Economic Area Citizen) and have lived in UK for 5 years. My wife is Lithuanian too. First proof of me being in UK is my NIN appointment (I had to be present in UK) that was on 1st of November 2010. I have worked in UK since (without more than 3 week breaks), own my house in UK, second child was born here.

[Based on information on gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/becoming-a-british-citizen/check-if-you-can-apply) I have been living in UK for 5 years and this allows me to apply for citizenship. (I qualify on other points too, passed the Language and Live in UK tests).

> There are different ways to become a British citizen. The most common is called ‘naturalisation’.
>
> You can apply for British citizenship by naturalisation if:
>
> - you’re 18 or over
> - you’re of good character, eg you don’t have a serious or recent criminal record, and you haven’t tried to deceive the Home Office or been involved in immigration offences in the last 10 years
> - you’ll continue to live in the UK
> - you’ve met the knowledge of English and life in the UK requirements
> - you meet the residency requirement
>
> And you must usually have:
>
> - lived in the UK for at least the 5 years before the date of your application
> - spent no more than 450 days outside the UK during those 5 years
> - spent no more than 90 days outside the UK in the last 12 months
> - been granted indefinite leave to stay in the UK (or permanent residence if you’re an EEA national) - this means there’s no specific date that you have to leave
> - had indefinite leave to stay in the UK for the last 12 months (or permanent residence if you’re an EEA national)
> - not broken any immigration laws while in the UK

Since [citizenship application fee is hefty](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/448606/Master_Fees_Leaflet_2015_07_21.pdf) (~£1k) I figured to [apply using NCS service](https://www.gov.uk/becoming-a-british-citizen/how-to-apply). I live in Hampshire so I went to [Hampshire nationality checking website](http://www3.hants.gov.uk/registration/citizenship/nationality-checking-service) and there requirements differ from those on gov.uk.

According to Hampshire council:

> EEA National applications must be submitted with documentary evidence of your residence during the qualifying period of either 6 years, or 5 years if married to a British Citizen.

This (in my eyes) is conflicting information between gov.uk and local authority.

**How long does one have to live in UK to apply for citizenship via naturalization if he is EEA citizen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual email thread between me and an immigration lawyer: http://nadinewongsolicitors.co.uk/contact-us

## Me

> I think I need to do more reading... But maybe you can clarify that
>   for me - to become British Citizen 5 years is enough?
>
> "lived in the UK for at least the 5 years before the date of your
>   application"
>
> If 5 years is enough then maybe we can apply for citizenship straight
>   away without intermediate step of permanent resident?
>
> (not entirely sure, my knowledge is limited)

## Lawyer

> To qualify for naturalisation as a British national you need to have at least one year with permanent residence, i.e. 5 years to get PR plus 1 >with PR = 6 to qualify.
>
> Please see this link:
>
> https://www.gov.uk/becoming-a-british-citizen/check-if-you-can-apply
>
> One of the requirements is that you:
>
> ·         “had indefinite leave to stay in the UK for the last 12 months (or permanent residence if you’re an EEA national)”
>
> If you want to be more precise go can see the Schedule 1 (2) (c ) of the BNA1981 which says:
>
> (c)that he was not at any time in the period of twelve months so ending subject under the immigration laws to any restriction on the period for >which he might remain in the United Kingdom;
>
> http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/61
>
> Sometimes the info is very confusing but you need 12 months with PR to qualify.

You need apply for **Permanent Residentship** *(5 years required)* first and then after a year for **Citizenship**.